# I am getting this error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my query. I am trying to update the new column in the table:

```
update [dbo].[I_InstallBase_Updated_1]
set updated_padid = (SELECT 
                         CASE 
                            WHEN LEN(padid) - LEN(REPLACE(padid,'.','')) > 1
                               THEN  LEFT(padid,CHARINDEX('.',padid,CHARINDEX('.',padid,1)+1)-1) 
                            ELSE padid -- if there are 1 or 0 dots(.) then return the entire value
                         END as updated, *
                     FROM 
                         [I_InstallBase_Updated_1]
                     WHERE 
                         serial_number LIKE 'SKE%' 
                         AND PARENT_INSTANCE_END_DATE IS NULL
                         AND INSTANCE_USAGECODE = 'IN_RELATIONSHIP' 
                         AND instance_status != 'Expired'
                         AND installed_location_type = 'HZ_PARTY_SITES' 
                         AND padid != 'n/a'
                         AND padid LIKE ('%.%')
                    )
```

I get this error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quick fix: Add `TOP(1)` to the `SELECT`, better fix: Change your logic so that subquery only returns a single value for the update.

Comment: Your select case has `  ,* `, making it return more than one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must only return one column in the subquery, so remove the `,*` part of the query.

The subquery must also only ever return one row (value) for the update, so you need to ensure that it has the appropriate where clause to enforce this, or as Tim mentions in his comment above, change the subquery to a `SELECT TOP(1)` if that isn't possible.

Comment: You might want to note that the subquery should also return only one record.